# zsh handlers like command_not_found_handler()

Tags: zsh, handle

I'd like to format the zsh output.

eg for unfound functions I now have:

```
function command_not_found_handler(){echo $fg[red]"\033[4m???\033[0m"$fg[red]" Command \"$1\" not found."}
```

which returns red text and underlined `???`.

I did this for the `command_not_found_handler` and would like to apply the same logic to other error output e.g.:

```
zsh: bad pattern: echo[
```

and

```
zsh: correct 'ehco' to 'echo' [nyae]?
```

yet I can't seem to find the names of the correct handlers. Do they even exist as handlers? If not is there a more general approach to changing the warning/error/info output in zsh?

A more general approach would be nice so that errors from other programs would also ge the same format. e.g.

```
cd: no such file or directory: no/dir
```

perhaps modify standard error output (I don't know if this even makes sense, I'm really tired...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out myself.

Using the c script [here](https://gist.github.com/1129908), and modifying it a bit, I got what I needed.

The modifying that took part was this: 
because I wanted the underlined `???` in front of each error, I changed the loop at line 107 to print ??? before looping over the rest of the error. This was down like so:

```
 if (buffer[0] == 27)
     dontcol = 1;
 if (buffer[0] == '\n')
     dontcol = 0;
 if (!dontcol)
     fputs(begstr, stdout);
     fputs("\0033[4m??? \033[0m", stdout);     
     putchar(buffer[0]);
 if (!dontcol)
     fputs(endstr, stdout);
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
              if (buffer[i] == 27)
                dontcol = 1;
              if (buffer[i] == '\n')
                dontcol = 0;
              if (!dontcol)
                fputs(begstr, stdout);
              putchar(buffer[i]);
              if (!dontcol)
                fputs(endstr, stdout);
}
```